# Cell Fracture Add-On Automatically Decimates Base Mesh

Tags: add-on

Wondering if anyone here can offer some advice on the Cell Fracture add-on.

I am trying to fracture some very high-poly triangulated 3D scans but it seems that the Cell Fracture add-on takes it upon itself to simplify the base mesh on it's own and the resulting fractured objects are very low res.

I looked into this and I see that about 2 years ago, the bundled Cell Fracture add-on had a lot more options than what are available now in 2.91. Specially, it appears that there was once a 'Simplify Base Mesh' option in the Cell Fracture setup (along with numerous other options) but they are no longer present in the add-on.

Even though it would appear that the 'Simplify Base Mesh" option has been removed, is it plausible that the add-on is applying this feature during the fracture process?

I would like to avoid Cell Fracture from simplifying my mesh.  I am also curious about why the current version of Cell Fracture has fewer options available than it appears to have in previous versions.

Example:

My original mesh before fracturing:
[image: 1]

The result. A decimated/simplified low-poly mesh:
[image: 2]

Current Cell Fracture options (v 2.91):
[image: 3]

Previous Cell Fracture options (v 2.8 - notice the 'simplify base mesh option, and others):
[image: 4]

(as seen in this youtube vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5guh5naT-XM)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply, but I have been running into this problem as well and managed to find a solution. I have a pretty high poly vase model I wanted fracture:

[image]

I run into the same problem you did, where the Cell Fracture add-on was decimating my model. It took me a while to figure out what was going on.

[image]

The answer to the problem lies in the settings menu for the add-on. I found it while fiddling around with the add-on and trying everything to try and fix the issue. Note that this is the newest version, and there is no checkmark that disables model simplification. However, by checking "Debug-Boolean", the add-on, for some reason, will not simply your model. The other settings did not matter and you can still adjust them to your preference.

[image]

As you can see, there is a nicely fractured vase that is free of decimating. **The debug option does come with the drawback that you have to apply the Boolean modifier on each generated piece** if you want to manipulate them, as high geometry boolean interactions are very slow.

I don't know if the debug option was intended to disable simplifying, but it does, and it works. I don't understand why they removed the disable simplifying option from the newest build, but I hope it can be added back. Anyways, best of luck on your work!

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. You arrived at the exact same solution as I did.  I should have come back to edit this thread sooner.  Your method of using the debug boolean seems to solve the issue and you're correct, it's quite a pain as each modifier has to be manually applied.  It's certainly a good enough work around for now.  I hope that they will take a look at this in a future update.